# Social Login With Cognito

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am trying to integrate into an app (iOS) social login (facebook) using Cognito. Till now I cannot find a clear documentation that shows the steps.

On the other hand I was able to integrate social login with Firebase into less than a day. Just I followed the steps on the docs. The process was simple. I requested the credentials from the facebook api and then sign in the firebase user, and thats it! I have an authenticated user and his email, name etc.

Is there anything that can be close to that behaviour with cognito? Or is there any documentation that I have missed?

Thanks

**Edit:**

I am in the phase where I have already done the communication with facebook below is the code:

```
let loginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
    loginManager.logIn(withReadPermissions: ["public_profile", "email"], from: self) { (result, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error)
        } else if (result?.isCancelled)! {
            print("CANCELED")
        } else {
            print("LOGED IN")
        }
     }
```

But I cannot see how to use the code from the documentation (below)

```
class FacebookProvider: NSObject, AWSIdentityProviderManager {
    func logins() -> AWSTask<NSDictionary> {
        if let token = AccessToken.current?.authenticationToken {
            return AWSTask(result: [AWSIdentityProviderFacebook:token])
        }
        return AWSTask(error:NSError(domain: "Facebook Login", code: -1 , userInfo: ["Facebook" : "No current Facebook access token"]))
    }
}
```

Comment: You mean documentation like this? http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/external-identity-providers.html

Comment: @MarkB I did update the question

Comment: Checkout the iOS sample at https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-ios-samples